How to apply launch template changes to an autoscaling group without replacing instances
I created a launch template and an autoscaling group from that launch template in AWS with fixed number of instances (desired_capacity = min_size = max_size).
Then I updated the launch template to modify user-data. Now I want to apply these changes to the existing instances of the autoscaling group without replacing any instance with new instance. Due to some hardware fingerprint logic at startup, we can't afford to keep replacing instances.
There's a feature called instance refresh to apply launch template changes to autoscaling group. However running that will terminate current intances and provision new instances. I want instances not to be replaced.
